# How to merge an object inside another object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I don't know if the question is right, but I want to do the following, I want the properties of "variable" to become part of the variable day.

The object being as follows: `{seg: 60, min:1, dias: 7, semana: 1}`

Remaining the object of the following way: Take into consideration that the object inside the object could be anyone and it does not have to be the property "variable" for what I would like to make it dynamic, reason why an arrangement like delete dia.variable and later to merge would not serve me.

With the code that I show you I have only obtained that the result is: `{seg: 60, min:1, variable:{dias: 7, semana: 1}, dias: 7, semana: 1}`

Any ideas on how I could do it more efficiently, and above all, do it.

```
const dia = {seg: 60, min:1, variable:{dias: 7, semana: 1}}
let varia = {}
let newDia = {}

const processJson = () => {
    Object.entries(dia).map(([name, value]) => {
        if(typeof(value) === 'object'){
            varia = value
            newDia = {...dia, ...variable}
        }
    })    
}

processJson()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a universal method for flatting any object with 2 levels deep. It uses the array [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method and the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function:

```js
const dia = { seg: 60, min: 1, variable: {dias: 7, semana: 1} }

function flatObject(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((result, key) => {
  
    // If there is a nested object, flat the object
    if (typeof o[key] === 'object' && ! Array.isArray(o[key]) && o[key] !== null) {
      for (const inKey in o[key]) {
        result[inKey] = o[key][inKey];
      }
    }
    // Just copy the value
    else {
      result[key] = o[key];
    }
    
    // Return accumulator
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(flatObject(dia))
```

Answer (score 1):

Start of by using a [destructuring assignement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the `seg`, `min` and `variable` properties from the `dia` object.

```
const { seg, min, variable } = dia;
```

Then create a new object in which you set the `seg` and `min` properties with the destructured properties. For the `variable` property, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to place the properties of `variable` inside the same object.

```
const result = {
  seg,
  min,
  ...variable
};
```

```js
const dia = {
  seg: 60,
  min: 1,
  variable: {
    dias: 7,
    semana: 1
  }
};

const { seg, min, variable } = dia;

const result = {
  seg,
  min,
  ...variable
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your code works for that particular example, but I want something dynamic because I don't know what properties I will get. Destructuring is of little use to me if I do not know the properties, your code for the example  `{gols: 70, games: {played: 120, mins: 700}}` would no longer be useful, since the same destructuring would have to be done manually and it would not be dynamic.

Comment: A, I see. So basically you would like to have a flattened object, correct? I'll look into it.

Comment: Yes, that's it!